# Name of color setting for background javascript in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, editor, settings, color-scheme

I use custom Color Scheme for Visual Studio editor Environment & Fonts and Colors.

I have a little problem with settings for JavaScript. If i have char '#' in name, background is different than others. If i remove char '#' everything is OK.

I would be happy if I have everywhere same background.

I have ReSharper too, but it doesn't matter because if i suspend them, background color is still wrong.

Can i ask you for help? Where is correct setting for set right background ?
I try change many settings but without results.

Thank you

With char #
[image: With char #]

Without char #
[image: Without char #]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might change "ReSharper Injected Language Background" background color and "ReSharper CSS id selector" foreground color.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much.